# Issue with FirebaseObjectObservable and CanActivate in Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I tell you my problem. I started an angular course on udemy. The point is that in the course they use angular 4 and I use angular 10, and I realized late about this change of versions. I've been migrating a lot of things from angular 4 to angular 10 throughout the course but it got me a blocker.

We are doing an exercise where we are doing a shoppingCart Web Site where I am doing an Admin user and therefore, this can only have access that common users cannot. I make the components and services of this but apparently the version of the procedures used by the instructor are different from the current version of angular.

I leave the code that shows the problem (with a comment indicating where it occurs):

User.service.ts => This is one of the components that gives me an error

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  save( user: firebase.User) {
    this.firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }

  //The error message is: Cannot find name 'FirebaseObjectObservable'
  get(uid: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<AppUser>{
    return this.firestore.collection('users').doc(uid);
  }
  
}
```

admin-auth-guard.service.ts => This is the other component that gives me an error

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AdminAuthGuardService implements CanActivate{
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService){
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.auth.user$
      //The error message is: Cannot find name "Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<User>'"
      .switchMap(user => (this.userService.get(user.uid))
      .map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
  }

}
```

App-user.ts

```
export interface AppUser{
    name: string;
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AdminOrdersComponent } from './admin/admin-orders/admin-orders.component';
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AdminProductsComponent } from './admin/admin-products/admin-products.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';
import { AdminAuthGuardService } from './admin-auth-guard.service';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireAnalyticsModule } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminProductsComponent,
    AdminOrdersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([

      {path: 'admin/products', component: AdminProductsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService, AdminAuthGuardService]},
      {path: 'admin/orders', component: AdminOrdersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService, AdminAuthGuardService]}
    ]),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAnalyticsModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuardService,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The firebase configuration is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 10 and "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2"**

First you need change something in your import,

```
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFireObject} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

and change `FirebaseObjectObservable` to `AngularFireObject`

I share a link for more details. You can take a look to the documentation
https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/93912bc3e9e41d48628a8671c766b0c2e8b65dc8